USDA NASS Cropland Data Layers corn map
I saw on the website that the CDL mask only started in 2008 https://agdatacommons.nal.usda.gov/articles/dataset/CropScape_-_Cropland_Data_Layer/24660315?file=44334368, but when I visualized it using Google Earth Engine, I found that I could still get some crop masks even if I set the time to before 2008, such as 2001. Could you please explain how these crop masks from before 2008 were generated?
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2001-12-31'))
                  .first();
var cropLandcover = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1);
Map.setCenter(-100.55, 40.71, 4);
Map.addLayer(cropLandcover, {}, 'Crop Landcover');

Also, if it's not real crop mask before 2008, how can I get the crop mask before 2008?
